# Ordenar con NSSortDescriptor

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Estoy intentando mostrar en una `UITableViewController` mis elementos guardados en Core Data en un orden específico dado por uno de sus atributos. Hay un atributo que puede ser 1 o 0 y mi intención es mostrar primero aquellos cuyo valor es 1.

```
NSFetchRequest *req = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MyContacts"];

req.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"value" ascending:YES]];

NSFetchedResultsController *results = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:req managedObjectContext:self.Model.context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

ContactsViewController *cVC = [[ContactsViewController alloc]initWithFetchedResultsController:results style:UITableViewStylePlain]`;
```

Este es mi código, pero no ordena la lista.

Cualquier ayuda sería estupenda.

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres que en el orden aparezca primero el `1` y luego el `0` debería ser con `ascending:NO`:

```
req.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"value" ascending:NO]];
```

Además, ¿qué es `@"value"`? Allí deberías poner el nombre de la propiedad de `MyContacts` por la que quieres ordenar (que tal vez se llame `value`...)

Comment: Claro, value es el atributo de mi entidad en `Core Data` por el que quiero ordenar. El problema es que no hace nada, aunque cambie el booleano de `YES` a `NO `. Es bastante raro.

Comment: En realidad el cambiarlo a `NO` te tendría que producir el efecto contrario al que deseas. `value` es un atributo de tipo booleano o entero en el Core Data Model?.

Comment: Mi proyecto se basa en sacar mis contactos del teléfono con `Contacts Framework` y guardarlo en core data en la entidad `MyContacts` que he creado. Actualmente muestro mis objetos mediante una clase que hereda de `UITableVIew` [enlace](http://www.migueldiazrubio.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/CoreDataTableViewController.zip) . 

Para probar he hecho una `FetchRequest` y he guardado los resultados en un `NSMutableArray`mostrándolos en una `UITableView`y aquí si funciona el `NSSortDescriptor` cosa rara...